# Could you help me translate this picture?

Tags: translation, character-identification, traditional-characters, handwriting, calligraphy

I got this picture frame as a present from my family, but I also really like the image even though I don't know what it means. I tried to find its meaning with google translate, and other image based translators but with no luck. Upon further inspection, I found the website which this poster was made and the artist: Hu Chen. But unfortunately the [website](https://www.artline-holland.com/artists/show/Hu/Chen) didn't help at all.

I know that the red mark is a seal, though, but I am still stuck.Can I have some help?

[image: Picture frameand image of Chinese character]

Comment: I don't see the painting on the website. Unless you can provide more information, only the seal (繞屋梅花三十樹) is interpretable, the calligraphy (啻泰) doesn't mean anything immediately apparent.

Comment: Thank you so much! Solving the seal looked impossible. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

The big characters look like 啻chì泰tài

啻 chì is a old word not common today I think.

泰 tài safe or peaceful calm also big (泰tài州zhōu is a city in Jiangsu province)

Together I don't know what they might mean.

As a guess, 啻 can mean 'remain, remainder'. (Jíyùn.zhìyùn is an 11th century dictionary)

啻: 余，剩下。《集韻•寘韻》：“啻，餘也。”
啻: remain, left over. <Jíyùn.zhìyùn>: "啻chì,remain"

啻泰：maybe: remain calm

As for the red scribble-de-gook, I will never be able to read that "seal script", but there are people here who can! Amazing!

Comment: “scribble-de-gook” interesting description  as the old proverb said: “never say never”, you can read it, if you wish 

Comment: What about the seal?

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time for researching. Remain calm seams like a good text for a poster. Now I'm sure I'm going to keep the image in the frame.

Comment: If, and only if my guess is correct, maybe, in modern parlance, the artist is just saying "chill". And yes, the frame is ugly!

Comment: Ok, I understand. Well it's a good thing it won't hang on your wall ;)